# Two right triangles with known hypotenuses and two known points

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm trying to write formula for calculating some movement paths for a two servo "leg", first servo being $\alpha$, and second servo being $\beta$, and distance from first servo to second servo is 7 cm, and the distance from the second servo to the end of the leg is 10 cm. End of the leg has to be 7 cm right and 4 cm down from the first servo (See the geometry from the image).

Calculating the needed movement paths requires essentially figuring out a formula to calculate lengths for AC (+ BC) and ED (+ BE) OR $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I was able to calculate the values with Wolfram alpha's system of equations solver, but I was unable to figure out the formulas I could use in my program to calculate the needed values ([Wolfram alpha functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sopXW.jpg))

the geometry:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$7\sin\alpha-10\cos\beta=-4$$$$7\cos\alpha+10\sin\beta=7$$
square them and add to each other
$$49-140(\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta)+100=65$$
$$140\sin(\alpha-\beta)=84$$
$$\alpha-\beta=\arcsin\frac{84}{140}=\arcsin\frac{3}{5}$$
Now you can turn back to image

[image]

You can see that $|BF|=\frac{21}5$ and $|AF|=\frac{28}5$

So $|AG|=\frac{28}{5\cos\beta}$

Then you have $7-\frac{28}{5\cos\beta}=4\tan\beta$ from the triangle GDD'

$$7\cos\beta-4\sin\beta=\frac{28}5$$
Divide this by $\sqrt{7^2+4^2}=\sqrt{65}$
$$\frac7{\sqrt{65}}\cos\beta-\frac4{\sqrt{65}}\sin\beta=\frac{28}{5\sqrt{65}}$$
$$\beta+\arccos\frac7{\sqrt{65}}=\arccos\frac{28}{5\sqrt{65}}$$

So $\beta=\arccos\frac{28}{5\sqrt{65}}-\arccos\frac7{\sqrt{65}}$ and $\alpha=\arccos\frac{28}{5\sqrt{65}}-\arccos\frac7{\sqrt{65}}+\arcsin\frac{3}{5}$

Comment: I just remembered a better keyword for the issue, inverse kinematics. After studying for a while, I realized that my approach was not optimal. Here is a similar situation, that is solved more efficiently: https://oscarliang.com/inverse-kinematics-and-trigonometry-basics/

Comment: @user3439124 Great, didn't know for this. That has some real purpose